# How can I double jump in my platform game code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in the middle of making a simple 2D platform game. I have successfully managed to make my box move left to right, and jump between platforms etc.

What I am hoping for it to be able to do is perform a double jump, where in mid air you can press the space bar again to jump in mid air once more.

I have tried the following code and it does not seem to be working for me. I just started using Unity and am really enjoying it however I could use a little advise on how I should go about changing a few things in my code to perform a double jump. Any advise would be appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(playerpysics))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Player Handling
    public float gravity = 20;
    public float speed = 8;
    public float acceleration = 25;
    public float jumpHeight = 12;
    private float doubleJump = 10;
    private float currentSpeed;
    private float targetSpeed;
    private Vector2 amountToMove;
    private playerpysics playerpysics;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start ()
    {
        playerpysics = GetComponent<playerpysics> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (playerpysics.movementStopped) 
        {
            targetSpeed = 0;
            currentSpeed = 0;
        }

        targetSpeed = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * speed;
        currentSpeed = IncrementTowards (currentSpeed, targetSpeed, acceleration);

        if (playerpysics.grounded) 
        {
            amountToMove.y = 0;

            if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) 
            {
                amountToMove.y = jumpHeight;
            } 
            else if (Input.GetButtonDown * 2 ("Jump"))
                amountToMove.y = doubleJump; 
        }

        amountToMove.x = currentSpeed;
        amountToMove.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        playerpysics.Move (amountToMove * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private float IncrementTowards (float n, float target, float a)
    {
        if (n == target) 
        {
            return n;
        } 
        else 
        {
            float dir = Mathf.Sign (target - n);
            n += a * Time.deltaTime * dir;
            return (dir == Mathf.Sign (target - n)) ? n : target;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: i havent tried anything yet, I am new to unity and as following a tutorial but it does not have double jump in the tutorial, was just wondering if anyone on here would be able to help me out a little, thanks!

Comment: At the moment you have a statement that makes your character jump and I assume that's working. What happens at the moment if you hit space bar again after you have jumped?

Comment: As you can see, the community has decided that this question is not specific enough. Rethink your question and try again.

Comment: Hey user, welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't get discouraged! The best questions here explain what the problem is, what they've already tried, where they're stuck, and what they are looking for specific guidance on. When people hear something like, *"How can I do this?"* on its own, they think you are looking for someone to do work for you, rather than trying to get past some roadblock that you've hit. If you could explain what you've tried, what is happening now, and what you want to happen, people will be much more willing to help. You can [edit] your post with that info, thanks in advance!

Comment: Well done jmac - constructive response to help a new user rather than simply downvoting.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah it probably was lacking information but edited it now! Just messing around with the code just now to see if anything works!

Comment: Just have a look at your reference tutorial again. Why is there a         `if (playerpysics.grounded)`? What does that ensure? So what will you have to do to make sure that you can jump even when in the air?

Comment: P.s. `else if (Input.GetButtonDown * 2 ("Jump"))` (which I assume is your attempt to make it work) will not do the trick. It's not valid code. Perhaps a good C# book would help you out. Something like http://www.manning.com/skeet3/ It will make things a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

In all my unity platformers I try do it the simplest posable way... Basically I have a int that counts the current number of jumps, and a int for max jumps

```
int jumpcount;
int maxjumps;

Public void Jump() {
    If (jumpcount >= maxjumps) {
        return;
    } 
    ... /whatever does a jump here
    Jumpcount++
 } 
//this will be called when physics calls a  Collision
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col){
    Jumpcount = 0;

}
```

[see OnCollisionEnter info here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/on-collision-enter)

This script can further be improved by adding a check to see what kind of object it had collided with, allowing for wall jumps, killer floors, and much more.

I do this with a simple `if(col.GameObject.Layer = somelayer)` but there is really no right way to check

Answer (score 0):

I also needed my character to double jump. But also, the second jump had to be "weaker". 
I solved it this way:

```
public bool jump;
float jumpForce = 0f; // Force added when the player jumps.
public float firstJumpForce = 0f;
public float secondJumpForce = 0f;

private bool canJump = false;
private int availableJumps = 2;

void Update () {

    if ((Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))) {
        jump = true; // I can jump
    }
}

//Update for physics steps. Regular intervals. 
void FixedUpdate(){

    if(jump && canJump)
    {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));

        // Can the player jump again??
        availableJumps--;
        if (availableJumps <= 0){
            canJump = false;
        } else {
            //I modify the second jump force
            jumpForce = secondJumpForce;
        }
        jump = false;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        canJump = true;
        availableJumps = 2;
        jumpForce = firstJumpForce;
    }
}
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Burdock thank you for that answer! I tried your code on my character and it works great except that when i used return for

```
    public void Jump () {
        if (jumpCount >= maxJumps){
            return;
    }
}
```

I found that it only let me do the jumping sequence once so I did

```
public void Jump (bool jump) {
        if (jumpCount >= maxJumps){
            jump = false;
    }
}
```

Then below I checked if I was grounded and then i would set the jumpCount = 0 and jump = true.

Thank you tho, I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to make a double jump with the Unity PlatformerCharacter2D script.